# JavaScript Variable Hoisting

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, hoisting

I'm having a problem understanding why name is getting a value here

```
(function() {
  (function() {
    var name = 'Fido';
  })();
})();

console.log(name + ' says woof'); //Output: Fido says woof
```

Shouldn't the variable name be local to the internal function?

Comment: The variable is local to the inner function. I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: So my console says "Fido says woof". It should say something like "undefined says woof"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable is local, and the value that you see doesn't come from the assignment inside the function.

You have named your window "Fido" also, and when you use `name` in the global scope, you get the `window.name` property.

If you try it in a jsfiddle, you will get "result says woof".

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/eDxf3/

Comment: I wonder if it's caching it somehow. I'm clearly getting Fido says woof instead of result

Comment: Okay, I closed the browser window and reloaded the page and now it just says "says woof". It must have been some caching issue since I was trying lots of different variations of this code to make sure it was doing what it was supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong! If executed in browser console this code will output:

 `says woof`

I think you need to understand hoisting better. [This article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) is definitely going to help you.
Here is a short description taken from the article:

---

In JavaScript, a name enters a scope in one of four basic ways:

- Language-defined: All scopes are, by default, given the names this and arguments.
- Formal parameters: Functions can have named formal parameters, which are scoped to the body of that function.
- Function declarations: These are of the form function foo() {}.
- Variable declarations: These take the form var foo;.

Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved (“hoisted”) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter. Function parameters and language-defined names are, obviously, already there. This means that code like this:

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    var x = 1;
}
```

is actually interpreted like this:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    bar();
    x = 1;
}
```

It turns out that it doesn’t matter whether the line that contains the declaration would ever be executed. The following two functions are equivalent:

```
function foo() {
    if (false) {
        var x = 1;
    }
    return;
    var y = 1;
}

function foo() {
    var x, y;
    if (false) {
        x = 1;
    }
    return;
    y = 1;
}
```

Comment: My console says "Fido says woof".

Comment: I wasn't wrong, but it looks like somehow Chrome was caching the variable somewhere. I quit the window and reloaded the page and things behaved normally. Whew. I hate it when logic doesn't work. Thanks for helping me try that.

Comment: @planetoftheweb make sure you understand hoisting and scoping better and next time you will be confident where to find such a problem

Comment: The problem was that I understood hoisting, but my browser was playing tricks on me. Once I refreshed, it did what I thought it should do. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pavel Nikolov, that was a really good explanation of what I thought should be happening, but wasn't.

Comment: _"You are wrong!"_- No, the OP described a console output that _actually happened,_ and went on to say that they thought the variable _should_ be local. That's not wrong. The expected behaviour they describe reflected correct understanding of scope.